# How to return to previous page and refresh it in php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can user return to the page he came from, and refresh its content, using PHP or javascript.

I've used this to get back to the page :

```
    header("Location: javascript:history.back(-1)");
```

but it needs to be refreshed after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot execute javascript in a PHP script.

In PHP you can make use of the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` variable in the `header()` statement like so

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] );
exit;
```

Its always a good idea to follow a `header()` statement with an `exit` or code execution will continue through the rest of the script as normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use javascript you can use `window.history.back()`

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: window.history.back(); do the same action what browser back button do, but it will not refresh the page, it will bring back to the cached version of that page.